# SQL: Combine first two lines of a text field

Tags: sql-server

For each record in our MS SQL Server database, there is a text field. We would like to combine the first two lines of this text field. I have tried researching on this site and on Microsoft technet, and I do not know the proper way to write this in SQL. But, I believe the logic would be as follows:

---

copy text until char(13) from original column to new column

in new column, replace char(13) with nothing

remove text until char(13) from original column

concatenate text in new column with “ | “

join old column to the right of new column

---

How would I write this as a query? Thank you. Database type: MS SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: some sample data with expected result

Comment: We definetly need some sample data and what you expect as output.

Answer (score 0):

In your select statement you want to:

- Check the [charindex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) of the char(13) of the text column, and
- make [substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) of that column once you know where the char(13) is.

Use those two functions and you'll get what you want =)

Example:

```
select SUBSTRING ( [YourTextColumn] ,0, CHARINDEX (char(13), [YourTextColumn] , 0 ) )
from YourTable
```

That will give you the first line of the column. You can check for the second line as well, just change the starting position of the charindex function.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  REPLACE(SUBSTRING(ColumnName, 0,
                          CHARINDEX(CHAR(13), ColumnName,
                                    CHARINDEX(CHAR(13), ColumnName, 0) + 1)),
                CHAR(13), '')
FROM    TableName
```